# urxvt doesnt render bitmap fonts correctly when using colors

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts, arch-linux, urxvt

Just like in the title, urxvt cuts lettters 'w' and 'm' only when using bitmap fonts and only when these letters are highlighted. I tried searching for an answer but I can't seem to find any. Here's a picture with urxvt(left) and Termite(right) both using the same color scheme and xos4 Terminus [click to see comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFMs6.jpg)